# Javascript if variable equals variable enable function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Here's my code:

```
function f1(){document.write(variable123)};

function f2(){
if(variable111) document.write('WOHO!'); 
};
variable111=false;


variable1 = 'text1';

variable2 = 'text2';

variable3 = 'text3';


variable123 = variable2

f1();f2();
```

I need to enable `function f2()` when I use `variable123 = variable1`.
Other ways `function f2()` should be disabled.

Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean when `variable123 === variable1`?

Comment: Yeah I found this answer by myself after just starting this thread. I needed to change if like you said to if(variable123 == variable1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to enable function f2() when I use variable123 = variable1

Then you can just write `f2` as:

```
function f2() {
   if (variable123 !== variable1) return;

   //rest of code
}
```

I always favor the `return` form over wrapping the whole code within a *if* block. It's more readable.

Also, may I suggest you to use a naming convention that suggests the function might not *do it's work*, like `doSomethingIfNeeded` instead of `doSomething`. I think it's more appropriate.

Comment: Actually it works better with variable123 == variable1 without return. I've tried to do variable123 !== variable1 || variable123 !== variable2 with return and it didn't came up working. So I'll better leave with no return. Anyway, thanks! :]

Comment: @Simon, Perhaps it's because you should use the `!=` operator, which doesn't enforce strict equality. That would be wierd however...